# Making changes to a QTextEdit without adding an undo command to the undo stack

Tags: qt, pyside, qtextedit

I'm looking for a way to change the `QTextCharFormat` of a `QTextEdit`'s `QTextBlock` without triggering the addition of an undo command. Let me explain:

The `QTextCharFormat` of a `QTextBlock` can be easily changed by using the `QTextCursor::setBlockCharFormat()` method.  Assuming we have a `QTextEdit` called `myTextEdit` whose visible cursor is within the text block we want to change, we can change the textblock's `QTextCharFormat` like so:

```
text_cursor = myTextEdit.textCursor()
text_cursor.setBlockCharFormat(someNewCharFormat)
```

The above code works fine, but it will also add an undo command to the `myTextEdit` undo stack.  For my own purposes, I would like to be able to change the `QTextCharFormat` of a `QTextBlock` **without adding an undo command to the `QTextEdit`'s undo stack.**

I considered temporarily disabling the undo/redo system with the `QTextDocument::setUndoRedoEnabled()` method, but that method also clears the undo stack, which I don't want to do.  I've also looked for other ways to change how the undo/redo system behaves, but I haven't found a way to get it to temporarily ignore changes.  I simply want to make a change to a `QTextEdit` without the undo/redo system registering the change at all.

Any tips or suggestions are appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: I think you may be out of luck, see [this qt-interest thread](http://www.archivum.info/qt-interest@trolltech.com/2006-10/01204/QTextEdit-temporary-undo-suppression.html) (which is a bit old, but it summarizes the issues quite well).

Answer (score 8):

You have to group this with previous modification. It is simple you have to surround code which does this modification with: `beginEditBlock` and `endEditBlock`. See [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtextcursor.html#beginEditBlock).

```
text_cursor = myTextEdit.textCursor()
text_cursor.beginEditBlock()
text_cursor.setCharFormat(someOtherCharFormat) # some previous modification
text_cursor.setBlockCharFormat(someNewCharFormat)
text_cursor.endEditBlock()
```

this way you will make a single commit for undo stack for any complex modification.

Comment: Hi Marek.  Thanks for the suggestion!  Unfortunately, this solution doesn't accomplish what I need.  I really need there to be no undo command added at all.  The reason I need this is that I am trying to expand the undo/redo system to track and change attributes of the overall program that it doesn't track by default.  This means that, when an action is undone, I am executing additional code that could be thought of as part of the undo action.  In my case, the setBlockCharFormat() method would be run **as part of** an undo, and therefore, should not add an undo command to the stack.

Comment: so try `undo` then inside edit block `redo` and than your change.

Comment: beginEditBlock() is exactly what collapses many operations into one undo/redo step. This was hard to find. Thanks! We were about to refactor QTextDocument to use QUndoStack. This saved us 1 week of work. 

Answer (score 4):

joinPreviousBlock() should do the trick:

```
cursor = self.textCursor()
cursor.joinPreviousEditBlock()
cursor.setPosition(start, QTextCursor.MoveAnchor)
cursor.setPosition(end, QTextCursor.KeepAnchor)
cursor.setCharFormat(fmt)
cursor.endEditBlock()
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use [QSyntaxHighlighter](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qsyntaxhighlighter.html). Extends it and implement `highlightBlock` func, and call `setFormat` in it to change format without making undo/redo stack. See [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qsyntaxhighlighter.html) for more detail.

If you feel QSyntaxHighlighter is not what you want, you can use [QTextLayout](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qtextlayout.html). It is low level api and its `setAdditionalFormats` func doesn't make any undo stack.

```py
range1 = QTextLayout.FormatRange()
range1.start = 0
range1.length = 10
range1.format = QTextCharFormat()
# additional ranges here...
textBlock.layout().setAdditionalFormats([range1, ...])
```

This is also used in the inside of QSyntaxHighlighter.