# Making undo/redo work well with QTextDocument's and "replaceAll" operations

Tags: qt, undo

How do I make a single 'replaceAll' operation be a single step in `QTextDocument`'s undo stack?

It does not use `QUndoStack`, it has it's own. :(

Answer (score 1):

Use `beginEditBlock()`/`endEditBlock()` to record all operations within as a single undo step, see the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/27113540/72312 for details.