# PyQt: Editing QTextEdit block format without adding it to Undo stack

Tags: python, pyqt, qtextedit

I have a problem which is very similar to [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27113262/making-changes-to-a-qtextedit-without-adding-an-undo-command-to-the-undo-stack). Sadly it did not get fully solved back then.

I have a custom `QTextEdit` widget in my PyQt application. I've added few features to it to make it fancier. Especially, I lately added a feature which, when a line is selected, uses `setBlockFormat` to color the line.

But swapping the format pushes the command to the `QTextEdit` undo stack, and I don't want to trigger this behaviour.

The previous topic did not get a proper answer. The "easier" way on paper would be to block it. However it does not seem to be possible to do that, is it?

The other (and harder) way would be to set the QTextEdit with a custom `QUndoStack`, which would only pushes key event, but I'm a bit lost with this solution, especially with the deletion of characters (basically I would want to have only typed/deleted text in the Undo stack).

Am I mistaken in my understanding of the topic? Is there a simple solution that I don't see?

**EDIT**: to answer the question, the purpose of highlighting the line is just to emphasize current line selection, nothing more. It's what is done in software such as Notepad++. Attached is a screenshot of the feature.[image: line highlighting]

Comment: What would be the purpose of coloring the line? Is it intended to highlight the selection even more? Can you show an image of the expected result?

Comment: Using a syntax highlighter to hightlight the current line would seem to be a pretty straightforward solution.

Comment: I have already a syntax highlighter used for some keyword, and I want to highlight the complete line (not just the words of the line). I like the visual effect it provides to the user.

Comment: @ThylowZ Please remember to add a comment whenever you edit the question based on user requests, we cannot follow all posts.

Comment: Sry for that, I did it yesterday in the night coming back from a dinner, and went too fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visually highlighting a portion of text should *never* directly affect the underlying QTextDocument.

While it's probably possible to achieve this by using a smart implementation of QSyntaxHighlighter (through overriding of [`highlightBlock()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsyntaxhighlighter.html#highlightBlock) and by setting block states), if you already have a syntax highlighter with custom states and user data, supporting this might become quite a handful.
Also, by trying to change the background color of text, the result is that any other highlighting that actually changes the background becomes invisible in the selection.

I propose another solution: overriding the text edit `paintEvent()` and use the text cursor selection to draw any highlighting *before* the default painting.

The procedure is the following:

1. create a list for the highlighted blocks;
2. connect the [`selectionChanged`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#selectionChanged) signal of the QTextEdit to a function that will:

   1. create a temporary list and check if any selection exists;
   2. cycle through each block of the document, and if the selection is contained in a block, add it to the list;
   3. if the default list is different from the temporary one, replace it and schedule an `update()` on the `viewport()` (important! Calling `textEdit.update()` is a no-op, since you need to update the contents of its scroll area)
3. in the `paintEvent()` override, check if a "highlighted" list of blocks exists, and then:

   1. query the [`documentLayout()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextdocument.html#documentLayout);
   2. create an empty QRect;
   3. iterate all "highlighted" blocks and get their [`blockBoundingRect()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstracttextdocumentlayout.html#blockBoundingRect) that will be merged with the QRect above;
   4. create a QPainter on the viewport and draw the resulting QRect;
4. call the basic implementation;

Now, this might be not very effective, especially starting from point `3.` and considering that QTextEdit calls `paintEvent()` every time the cursor "caret" blinks. The solution is to "cache" the highlighted rectangle using [QPicture](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpicture.html), so that you don't need to compute everything at each paint event. The only requirement is to clear that cache whenever the text edit is resized, since the layout might change the bounding rect of each block.

Here is the result (using `NoWrap` to show the result with scrolling):

[image: screenshot of the example]

...and the code:

```py
class HighlightTextEdit(QTextEdit):
    highlightCache = None
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.highlightBlocks = []
        self.selectionChanged.connect(self.highlightSelection)

    def highlightSelection(self):
        cursor = self.textCursor()
        highlightBlocks = []
        if cursor.hasSelection():
            selectionStart = cursor.selectionStart()
            selectionEnd = cursor.selectionEnd()
            block = self.document().begin()
            while block.isValid():
                blockStart = block.position()
                blockEnd = blockStart + block.length()
                if blockEnd > selectionStart:
                    # the block probably contains the selection
                    if blockStart > selectionEnd:
                        # the block begins before the end of the selection:
                        # we can ignore it and any other block after it
                        break
                    highlightBlocks.append(block)
                block = block.next()
        if self.highlightBlocks != highlightBlocks:
            self.highlightBlocks = highlightBlocks
            self.highlightCache = None
            self.viewport().update()

    def updateHighlightCache(self):
        if not self.highlightBlocks:
            self.highlightCache = None
            return

        docLayout = self.document().documentLayout()
        rect = QRectF()
        for block in self.highlightBlocks:
            rect |= docLayout.blockBoundingRect(block)

        self.highlightCache = QPicture()
        qp = QPainter(self.highlightCache)
        qp.setPen(Qt.NoPen)
        color = self.palette().color(QPalette.Highlight)
        color.setAlphaF(max(.5, color.alphaF() * .5))
        qp.setBrush(color)
        qp.drawRect(rect)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        if self.highlightBlocks:
            if self.highlightCache is None:
                self.updateHighlightCache()
            qp = QPainter(self.viewport())
            # translate according to the scroll bars
            qp.translate(
                -self.horizontalScrollBar().value(), 
                -self.verticalScrollBar().value()
            )
            self.highlightCache.play(qp)

        super().paintEvent(event)
        
    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        super().resizeEvent(event)
        self.updateHighlightCache()
```

Note that the above is quite effective, since you can do whatever you want with the given bounding rects. For instance, instead of just drawing a merged rectangle, you could create "expanded" rects of each block and add them to a QPainterPath as *rounded* rects:

```py
    def updateHighlightCache(self):
        if not self.highlightBlocks:
            self.highlightCache = None
            return

        docLayout = self.document().documentLayout()
        path = QPainterPath()
        path.setFillRule(Qt.WindingFill)
        for block in self.highlightBlocks:
            rect = docLayout.blockBoundingRect(block)
            path.addRoundedRect(rect.adjusted(-1, -1, 1, 1), 2, 2)

        self.highlightCache = QPicture()
        qp = QPainter(self.highlightCache)
        qp.setPen(Qt.NoPen)
        color = self.palette().color(QPalette.Highlight)
        color.setAlphaF(max(.5, color.alphaF() * .5))
        qp.setBrush(color)
        qp.drawPath(path)
```

Another important aspect is that if the QTextDocument contains rich text with *laid out* items (such as table cells or inner frames), the selection might only include the rectangle of that block. In that case, if you still want to highlight the *horizontal* bounding rect, you need to *merge* the rectangle of the bounding rects with the rectangle of the whole document (the "top frame"), while considering the document margins:

```py
    def updateHighlightCache(self):
        if not self.highlightBlocks:
            self.highlightCache = None
            return

        docLayout = self.document().documentLayout()
        rect = QRectF()
        for block in self.highlightBlocks:
            rect |= docLayout.blockBoundingRect(block)
        topRect = docLayout.frameBoundingRect(self.document().rootFrame())
        margin = self.document().documentMargin()
        rect.setLeft(topRect.x() + margin)
        rect.setRight(min(rect.right(), topRect.right() - margin * 2))

        self.highlightCache = QPicture()
        qp = QPainter(self.highlightCache)
        qp.setPen(Qt.NoPen)
        color = self.palette().color(QPalette.Highlight)
        color.setAlphaF(max(.5, color.alphaF() * .5))
        qp.setBrush(color)
        qp.drawRect(rect)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your very detailed answer musicamante (it's not the first time that you provide your valuable knowledge).

I effectively thought of using paintEvent but my current knowledge on the topic is really low (to say the least), I'm really glad you came with such a deep solution.

I'll try to implement this as soon as I can (maybe not during the WE). The only paintEvent I have is the one you can see on the screenshot, which provide line numbers.

I'll use your answer as a way to train myself and improve my knowledge on this aspect of Qt. Getting back to you soon.

Comment: So I've reproduced your code, and it worked almost as I intended.

The only thing is that, as you can see in my screen, I want to highlight the line not only on selection, but also on cursor click (was probably not clear in my post).

The only thing I had to do was therefore to remove the `hasSelection` check on cursor and it worked perfectly fine. I'm really grateful for your help.

Comment: @ThylowZ you're very welcome! Remember that if an answer solves your issue, you should mark it as accepted by clicking the gray tick mark on its left.

Comment: Glad you said it, in my mind I did it but nope, I ticked the upvote instead of the answer validation.